# React-tools: Is Babel-CLI needed when I use Browserify with Babelify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, babeljs

Usually I've installed Babel-CLI on every system on which I liked to program with React.

Today I've seen a package.json files which contains Browserify, Babelify together with Babel-Preset-React in the dependencies but no Babel-CLI.

No I'm wondering:

Is it still necessary to have Babel-CLI on the system when I use Browserify, Babelify with React-settings?
Or **is Browserify-Babelify enough for getting the job done** and I can forget about Babel-CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Browserify and Babelify to build a bundle - and you always run your application by loading the bundle - you do not need Babel-CLI.